# Meaning of しつこい when it describes 霊

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the the below the person was asking whether there are many ghosts/spirits at the place (in this case the theme park)

> 「霊は？多いかな？多くても、**しつこくなければまだいい**んだけど」
> 「それはわからない、かな……。」
> 霊の多寡に言及しているレポートは、さすがにどこを探してもない

The sentence in question has her questioning whether there are many ghosts/spirits, and then she says even if there are many, as long as ..... then that is not as bad / is better.

However the meaning of しつこい in this context isn't clear to me. I am generally familiar with しつこい when used in the sense of "persistant" but I'm not quite sure how to understand it in this context.

Comment: I believe it might refer to the second meaning of しつこい which is to overflow with, too rich (taste). So I'd say the sentence would be something along the lines of : "Even if there are many, as long as the place isn't overflowing with them, it'll be fine. But that's just my guess from a bit of googling as this is slightly out of my range of knowledge

Comment: しつこい in terms of people has more to do with "persistent" with overtones of "bothersome" and "overbearing" -- i.e. they won't stop and won't go away.  So in this case, "yeah, even if there are a lot of ghosts, I'm still fine with that so long as they're not too overbearing."  Or something similar.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

しつこい霊 simply refers to annoying ghosts that refuse to go away. Maybe they are consistently trying to bother or haunt people. Maybe they are not going to harm people directly but are immune to the ordinary exorcizing means she has.